# Show page only once when app is installed in UWP

Tags: windows, uwp

I am developing a UWP windows 10 application and I want to have a page that is only shown at the start of launching application first time. It should not be shown when the app is opened second time in a system.

I have searched online about it but couldn't find any thing about it.

Comment: I think you can implement it like this - declare variable in localsettings responsible for this, let's say *IsFirstTime* - it should be boolean with default false value. Then find in app.xaml.cs code responsible for navigating to MainPage, check you IsFirstTime value if it's not true, navigate to your onetime page, if true, navigate to MainPage.

Comment: Can you explain, what do you mean by localsettings?

Comment: Please take a look at [this MSDN site](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/app-settings/store-and-retrieve-app-data) - you can easily find more information, by googling 'localsettings uwp'.

Comment: @Romasz, I have read this doc, but where should i write variable declaration, so that its default value initialization may not be read again. I have added this line localSettings.Values["IsFirstTime"] = true; inside constructor of app.xaml.cs.

Comment: I would add/modify the variable once user has successfully loaded you onetime page. Once it's set true it won't be fired again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know that my answer can be refined more, but i have done with spending 2 minutes and its **working** for me. I have added a page loaded event in my StartPage.xaml.cs file and added the following code inside it.

```
 if (localSettings.Values["IsFirstTime"] == null)
        {
            localSettings.Values["IsFirstTime"] = true;
        }

        if ((bool)localSettings.Values["IsFirstTime"])
        {
            localSettings.Values["IsFirstTime"] = false;
            this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage));
        }
```

Make sure you make a localSettings object at class level (of type ApplicationDataContainer). Now inside App.xaml.cs, I have added global variable for local settings as follow.

```
 Windows.Storage.ApplicationDataContainer localSettings = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings;
```

Inside app.xaml.cs file come to the if condition showing **rootFrame.Content == null** and replace every thing inside it with the following code.

```
 object value = localSettings.Values["IsFirstTime"];

            if (localSettings.Values["IsFirstTime"] != null)
            {
                if ((bool)value)
                {
                    rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(StartPage), e.Arguments);
                    localSettings.Values["IsFirstTime"] = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage), e.Arguments);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(StartPage), e.Arguments);
                localSettings.Values["IsFirstTime"] = false;
            }
```

I have tried it by uninstalling my app and run again to see if start page is shown (and it shows up). Second time when i open, MainPage is shown).

Answer (score 1):

In `App.xaml.cs` look for the `OnLaunched` handler. There are these lines of code for "switching" pages:

```
 if (rootFrame.Content == null)
 {
      rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage), e.Arguments);
 }
```

As @Romasz suggested in comments, you can add here additional logic with local (or better - roaming) storage to check whether app is launched for the first time:

```
            var roamingSettings = ApplicationData.Current.RoamingSettings;
            if (roamingSettings.Values.ContainsKey("NotFirstTimeLaunch"))
            {
                rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage), e.Arguments);
            } else
            {
                roamingSettings.Values["NotFirstTimeLaunch"] = true;
                rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(FirstLaunchPage), e.Arguments);
            }
```

Comment: +1, though I'm not sure if I wouldn't set the setting's value somewhere in *FirstLaunchPage's* loaded event - in case navigation fails. Though this is rather very rare case.